# How to print a dictionary made up of lines from a file in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary, file-io

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

I have a dictionary made up of lines extracted from a file like this:

```
Danny Shalev, 050-1111111, aaa@aaa.com
Gil Rom, 050-2222222, bbb@bbb.com
Tal Yakir, 050-3333333, ccc@ccc.com
```

Edit: my goal is for the dict to be printed out like this:

```
Danny Shalev - 050-1111111 - aaa@aaa.com
Gil Rom - 050-2222222 - bbb@bbb.com
Tal Yakir - 050-3333333 - ccc@ccc.com
```

The first name is the key, and the rest are the values.

I have written the code for converting the file lines into a dict, and I want to print out all values from my dictionary in a specific format, which would be line by line, separated by "-". I have already written the function print_person, to print it out in this format, I just want to apply this function (from the previous class) into my dict.

Here's the code:

```
class Person:
def __init__(self, name, phone,email):
    self.name = name
    self.phone = phone
    self.email = email

def print_person(self):
    return (str(self.name)+" - "+str(self.phone)+" - "+str(self.email))

class AddressBook:

def __init__ (self):
    self.contactsdict = {}

def add(self, newContact):
    self.contactsdict[newContact.name] = newContact.phone + " - " + newContact.email 


def search(self, name):
    return (self.contactsdict.get(name))

def addFromFile(self, fileName):
    f = open("contacts.txt") 
    for line in f:
        (key, val, val2) = line.split(",")
        self.contactsdict[key] = val + " - " + val2
    f.close

def printAddressBook(self):

    for key, val in self.contactsdict.items():
        Person.print_person


address = AddressBook() # make an instance

p1=Person("Danny Shalev","050-1111111","aaa@aaa.com")
print (p1.print_person())
address.add(p1)
address.addFromFile("contacts.txt")
address.printAddressBook()
```

I believe the problem is in this section, since I don't know how to use the method:

```
def printAddressBook(self):

for key, val in self.contactsdict.items():
    Person.print_person
```

Comment: Then I get this error:                                                                        
    TypeError: print_person() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
for key, val in self.contactsdict.items():
    Person.print_person
```

deconstructs all your dictionary entries into 2 variables, one the `key`, the other the `val`ue. The second line is incorrrect - Person is your class, you need an instance of the class to use the defined print method on it. 
You can call `val.print_person()` on each instance of the class `Person` to print each IF you store Persons in your inner dictionary. Classes are "templates" how a class is constructed - the instance must be used to call its functions. Currently your code only stores string in the internal dictionary.

To add persons to your internal Dict replace

```
for line in f:
    (key, val, val2) = line.split(",")
    self.contactsdict[key] = val + " - " + val2
```

with

```
for line in f:
    (key, val, val2) = line.split(",")
    self.contactsdict[key] = Person(key,val,val2) # create instances of Persons
        # and store them in the dictionary by there name
        # you get collisions if your file contains persons with identical names
```

Fixed code (this and some other errors marked with comments):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, phone,email):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email

    def print_person(self):
        return (str(self.name) + " - " + str(self.phone) + " - " + str(self.email))

class AddressBook: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.contactsdict = {}

    def add(self, newContact):
        self.contactsdict[newContact.name] = newContact  # store the Person instance 
                                                         # under its name as key 

    def search(self, name):
        return (self.contactsdict.get(name))

    def addFromFile(self, fileName):
        f =  open("contacts.txt")
        for line in f:
            (key, val, val2) = line.split(",")
            self.add(Person(key,val,val2)) # create Person and use own add-Function 
                                           # to add it to internal dictionary
        f.close

    def printAddressBook(self): 
        for key, val in self.contactsdict.items():
            print( val.print_person() ) # you need to print the output 
                                        # of print_person() - it currently only 
                                        # returns the string and does not print it  

address = AddressBook() # make an instance
p1 = Person("Danny Shalev","050-1111111","aaa@aaa.com")
print(p1.print_person())
address.add(p1)
address.addFromFile("contacts.txt") 
address.printAddressBook()
```

## Search returns a person, so you can use it to change persons inside your dict:

```
print("")
p = address.search("Danny Shalev")
p.name = "Hallo"   # change the name of the found person (the key will still be "Danny Shalev")
address.printAddressBook()
```

Output:

```
Danny Shalev -  050-1111111 -  aaa@aaa.com
Gil Rom -  050-2222222 -  bbb@bbb.com
Tal Yakir -  050-3333333 -  ccc@ccc.com

Hallo -  050-1111111 -  aaa@aaa.com   # after change of searched person
Gil Rom -  050-2222222 -  bbb@bbb.com
Tal Yakir -  050-3333333 -  ccc@ccc.com
```

Comment: @YasmimFranceschi Mhh - you are not adding `Persons` to your dictionary but concatenated strings from the file - see edit on how to fix that

Comment: @YasmimFranceshci - why are you not using your Add-Method btw. And why does it also only put strings into the dict? You wrote the code?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the code. I have a dict and the homework task demands me to use print_person to print each item according to the format in the method print_person.  But nevermind the error, it was my mistake..

Comment: @YasmimFranceschi  I fixed the issues  If ok so, pls mark answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, it looks great, but I was getting results in a weird form: {'Danny Shalev': <__main__.Person object at 0x03C208F0>} :                             
  So I replaced print for return in this section:                                             
      def search(self, name):
                                                                                                                              print (self.contactsdict.get(name))

Comment: @YasmimFranceschi the search returns you a Person-Object - you can either Print it or store it:    `searchedPerson = address.search("Danny Shalev")` and then use / manipulate `searchedPerson` - f.e. by `print(searchedPerson.print_person())`  -- maybe you should rename `print_person()` to `return_person_as_string()` which is more accurate in what it does. Or add a `print( ..... ) ` into the implementation of `print_person()` - function on your class `Person` -You can also change the persons name inside the dict if you use `searchedPerson.name = "Hallo"`